# Помогите создать DialogFragment с помощью View

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь создать AlertDialog через фрагмент, реализованный в отдельном классе. Хочу использовать специальную view для отображения диалога, со своими кнопками и т.д., но андроид студия ругается. Почему? Мой код:

```
public class NewDialogs extends DialogFragment {

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View mView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_new, null);

    Button yes = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
    Button no = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);

    mBuilder.setView(mView);

    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
```

// и далее по тексту
                }
Система выдает такую ошибку:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4310)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4146)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4118)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:603)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:514)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
>                                                                                     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
>                                                                                     at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:499)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2244)
>                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1002)
>                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: View mView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_new, null);  это нужно делать в onCreateView . Диалог по сути тот же фрагмент, только не расчитывай что свёрстанная view станет как надо, придётся с бубнами потанцевать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, кажется, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Переопредели метод `public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style)` и в нём

```
View parent = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog, null);
dialog.setContentView(parent);
```